# Web scraping data from an interactive line chart

Tags: r, web-scraping, web, rvest

I am trying to read the data in the time series plots shown [here](https://www.straitstimes.com/multimedia/graphics/2022/06/singapore-dengue-cases/index.html?shell#:%7E:text=Singapore%20is%20currently%20seeing%2030,lower%20than%20the%202020%20surge)- cases by week and year plot.

I was trying to use rvest package in R

```
selector <- "#chart > div > svg.svg-main > g > g > g:nth-child(2) > g.lines > g:nth-child(2) > path"

url <- "https://www.straitstimes.com/multimedia/graphics/2022/06/singapore-dengue-cases/index.html?shell#:~:text=Singapore%20is%20currently%20seeing%2030,lower%20than%20the%202020%20surge"

read_data <- function(url, selector){
  url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_element(css = selector) %>%
    html_table()
  
}
read_data(url, selector)
```

Above did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `read_html()`?

Comment: It is a function in rvest package in R to tread all of the HTML into R

Comment: Okay, perhaps I should have been more clear. What is the output of `url %>% read_html()`? The reason I ask is because this could provide insight into why it is failing. Perhaps it is because the returned HTML does not contain valid HTML. For example, if the Web server has some kind of scraping protection then it may return a 500 response.

Comment: The output is as follows:                                                                             
  {html_document}
<html data-vue-meta-server-rendered="" lang="en">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equi ...
[2] <body itemscope itemtyp ...

Answer (score 0):

Found in the network section of the developer tool

```
"https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/IbOE7/10/dataset.csv" %>%  
  read_csv() 

# A tibble: 5 × 54
   name `data/0` `data/1` `data/2` data/…¹ data/…² data/…³ data/…⁴ data/…⁵ data/…⁶ data/…⁷
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1  2018       54       45       48      50      50      28      30      37      51      37
2  2019      207      245      215     222     182     138     235     182     157     134
3  2020      303      343      404     309     370     400     380     381     374     375
4  2021      195      166      153     136     141     144     148     146     140     145
5  2022      105      146      180     171     154     169     206     199     263     370
# … with 43 more variables: `data/10` <dbl>, `data/11` <dbl>, `data/12` <dbl>,
#   `data/13` <dbl>, `data/14` <dbl>, `data/15` <dbl>, `data/16` <dbl>, `data/17` <dbl>,
#   `data/18` <dbl>, `data/19` <dbl>, `data/20` <dbl>, `data/21` <dbl>, `data/22` <dbl>,
#   `data/23` <dbl>, `data/24` <dbl>, `data/25` <dbl>, `data/26` <dbl>, `data/27` <dbl>,
#   `data/28` <dbl>, `data/29` <dbl>, `data/30` <dbl>, `data/31` <dbl>, `data/32` <dbl>,
#   `data/33` <dbl>, `data/34` <dbl>, `data/35` <dbl>, `data/36` <dbl>, `data/37` <dbl>,
#   `data/38` <dbl>, `data/39` <dbl>, `data/40` <dbl>, `data/41` <dbl>, …
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: How did you locate "https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/IbOE7/10/dataset.csv"

Comment: one issue was the above script doesn't read 2022 last few values and 2023 values

Comment: Yes, that is an issue